When using useConnection, onAccountChange doesn't work
It works fine when setting up connection with a custom RPC provider but not with useConnection(from @solana/wallet-adapter-react). I don't get any error, it just doesn't work.
When I try to connect via:
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"), "confirmed");

I get(in console) ws error: undefined;
I get that running websockets on public endpoints might be pricy, but if you found a solution...
